# MacOS 10.13.6 Can't delete or remove applications

Tags: macos, system-information

I can't locate the following files. I have removed it manually at file finder but it is still stuck here at the system information. Now I can't update my MacOs because I am running out of space.

If I click on Go Application or right click on Delete files. It doesn't work. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What application are you trying to remove? Have you tried with an uninstaller tool?

For exemple, you can follow this to fully uninstall Office 2011: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/troubleshoot-office-2011-for-mac-issues-by-completely-uninstalling-before-you-reinstall-ba8d8d13-0015-4eea-b60b-7719c2cedd17

Many application has the same type of uninstaller.

Comment: I am trying to remove all the games, Unturned and all of the above.

Answer (score 1):

About this Mac is a slow application in terms of file listing and deleting, especially in case of such big files. The reason I can guess is that it is build atop Finder and requires a huge amount of sorting and storage computations. Also apps like Xcode which were installed from Mac App Store will require passwords while emptying trash if not now.

I suggest that you find the uninstaller of all the apps in their DMGs, if any.

For the remaining ones, I suggest that you check their official pages for uninstallation.

As a last and deprecated option for the remaining ones, go to Finder's `Go` menu-> Applications -> delete specific apps or folders. Adding to this, there might be files in `~/Library` folder like caches or application support. To remove them, go to Go menu in Finder, hold `option` key and press Library-> go to Caches -> find the relevant files and delete the ones of your games.

Don't delete your Xcode developer files as they might be helpful for some later builds and contain Logs.