# Can't find application seen in storage management

Tags: finder, applications, storage

Question above. I have deleted "Rocket League" from my applications folder and deleted the entire trash.

I downloaded the app via Steam. I checked all the folders people said the app was downloaded in and saw a tiny directory inside `/Users/<name>/Library/Application Support` but definitely was not 8GB.

Clicking "Delete..." or "Show in Finder" in the Storage Management app does nothing.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: After selecting the app, can you see the Show in Finder button towards the bottom of the Storage Management app?

Comment: Yes, when I click it the title bar changes to say "Finder" but the finder never opens.

Comment: Try doing it with some other installed app and see if that works.

Comment: It opened it up in the finder as aspected, for another app.

Comment: I find it common, not normal though, for big apps. You could try a restart . https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361812/macos-10-13-6-cant-delete-or-remove-applications/361819#361819 (notify me by @ankii)

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?